# Selecting largest number from row

Tags: php, c++, mysql

Hello I need to select the largest average from each row. Is there an easy way to do this in SQL, or should I perform the comparison in a higher level language such as PHP?

[image]

Comment: have you tried something like `SELECT MAX(your_average_col)` ? [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: use voting;

select  state, max(avg(perDem)),max(avg(perGOP)),max(avg(perIND))
from polls
group by state; gives me an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a built-in from mySQL `SELECT MAX(your_average_col)` -> [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column.html)

```
$query = " SELECT col1, col2, MAX(colAVG) AS maxAVG FROM my_table ";
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$results = $stmt1->execute();
$stmt1->bind_result($col1, $col2, $maxAVG);
$stmt1->store_result();

if ($stmt1->num_rows > 0) {
while($stmt1->fetch()){
    echo"[ $col1 -> $col2 -> $maxAVG ]<br />";
}
}
else
{ echo"[ no data ]"; }
```

**IMPORTANT** : even if answer was accepted, I think it might be useful to protect column names with backticks as they have () in their names.

Comment: Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function I get this error

Comment: have you read the link to the doc ? it's a link, you need to select the best function for what you want to achieve. Then, show us the complete query...

Comment: what **exactly** do you need to achieve ? show an example of output please

Comment: basically I would want a new output with the name of the state the name of the winning collumn and the value of the winning column for example              alaska per(gop) 45.870

Comment: like -> `California / 53.3871` ?

Comment: Yes exactly like California / 53.3871 but maybe also the name of the column too like gop

Comment: Thank you  I was thinking about using php aswell but wasnt sure if it was easier to do using purely sql

Comment: much faster with DB built-in function, better let mySQL do the dirty job :)

Comment: @lolsharp : **IMPORTANT** : I think it might be useful to protect column names with backticks as they have () in their names